# Trying to wrap my head around observer class

Tags: python, observer-pattern

I'm trying to understand an observer class, but I don't understand how to implement it in practice.

I have a class that has 4 functions in relation to a .txt database- add student, delete student, sort and show student database, and search a student. I want it to send out an automatic message to all students when another student is added or deleted.

This is what I have so far, based off a guide I've been looking at:

```
class ObservableEvent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = []
    
    def register_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)

    def notify_allStudents(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for student in self.students:
            student.notify(self, *args, **kwargs)

class Observer:
    def __init__(self, observable):
        observable.register_student(self)
    
    def notify(self, message, observable):
        print("Got", message, "From", observable)

subject = ObservableEvent()
student = Observer(subject)
```

I think its just the last part I'm having the biggest issue with (I hope), concerning the notify_allStudents part. Whenever I try to pass more than 1 positional argument, it doesn't work. So far I have this:

```
class Student():    

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    pass
    
    def AddStudent(self, data):

        firstName = input('First Name: ')
        lastName = input("\nLast Name: ")
        email = input('\nEmail Address: ')
        campus = input('\nCampus: ')

        year = '22'

        generated_id = firstName[0:3] + lastName[0:3] + year

        newStudent = [generated_id, firstName, lastName, email, campus]

        f = open(data, "a")
        f.write('\n')
        for info in newStudent:
            f.write(info)
            f.write('\t')
        f.close()
        pass
```

Then here is where I have the above ObserverEvent and Observer classes.
And here is the rest:

```
ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Welcome to the QUICK SORT / LINEAR SEARCH Program

    1.ADD NEW STUDENT
    2.DELETE STUDENT
    3.SHOW STUDENTS
    4.SEARCH STUDENT
    5.ADD COURSE TO STUDENT
    Type EXIT to quit the application
    """)
    
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ") 
    
    if ans=="1": 
        print("""
        *******************

        STUDENT ADD MENU

        *******************
        """)
  
        Student.AddStudent(input, "studentMockData_AS2.txt")
        print("\nStudent Added")
        subject.notify_allStudents("A student has been added to the database.")
```

I'm currently getting this in the console: `Got <__main__.ObservableEvent object at 0x00000154909BB460> From A student has been added to the database.`

I'm honestly really lost on this. The example I was given was `subject.notify_observers("test", kw="python")`, but the *args and **kwargs are really throwing me. It throws an error of too many positional arguments if I include more than 1, but I thought the whole point of kwargs was to input more than 1. I'm also not sure why I would need to use a dict in this scenario. I don't even understand what I'm not understanding about this, but clearly I'm not doing it right. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: I'm aware that my class Student is badly done, but I have to leave it as is.

Comment: I'm not sure you intended this, but `student.notify(self,*arguements...)` is going to pass the `ObservableEvent` object as the first parameter.  That means your `def notify(self, message, observable):` should actually be `def notify(self, observable, message):`.  Beyond that, it's all working properly.

Comment: The "*args, **kwargs" thing is just a way to forward all the incoming parameters to the notification callbacks.  The code you have couldn't cause "too many positional arguments", so you aren't showing us the code that called that.